# Kerberos Server and logs

Tags: ubuntu, logging, kerberos

I'm attempt to set up a Kerberos server, and am running into some sort of issue with the configuration message. Unfortunately, the daemon refuses to tell me what went wrong; it tells me to "see log file", but never mentions *what* log file.

```
 # service krb5-kdc start
 krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm EXAMPLE.COM - see log file for details
 # ls /var/log/k*
 /var/log/kern.log
 # krb5kdc
 krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm EXAMPLE.COM - see log file for details
 # strace krb5kdc 2>&1 | grep write
 write(2, "krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm"..., 72krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm EXAMPLE.COM - see log file for details
 #
```

Is it lying to me? Does there even exist a log file?

Answer (score 5):

`/var/log/auth.log`. I would never have looked there.

Here's how I found it:

1. Noticed there was a `sendto` in the output of strace that started with a date/time, like a log might have.
2. Isolated it:

   ```
   # strace krb5kdc -n 2>&1 | grep sendto
   sendto(3, "<35>Feb 13 17:43:41 krb5kdc[2400"..., 115, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 115
   ```
3. Search for the call to `socket`, to see where that's going.

   ```
   # strace krb5kdc -n 2>&1 | grep 'socket\|connect'
   socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
   connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
   ```
4. Figure out where `/dev/log` goes, but I'm figuring the system logger at this point:

   ```
   # netstat -xp | grep /dev/log
   unix  5      [ ]         DGRAM                    7731     671/rsyslogd        /dev/log
   ```
5. Doesn't really tell me where, but going back to original `strace`, we can ask `strace` to not truncate the string:

   ```
   # strace -s 1000 krb5kdc -n 2>&1 | grep sendto
   sendto(3, "<35>Feb 13 17:47:05 krb5kdc[24194]: LDAP bind dn value missing  - while initializing database for realm EXAMPLE.COM", 115, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 115
   ```
6. `rsyslog` is probably logging somewhere in `/var/log`, and I now have the log message. Just `grep` for it:

   ```
   # cd /var/log && grep -R * -e 'LDAP bind dn'
   «tons of hits in auth.log»
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Logging for the KDC is usually configured in either `/etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` (sometimes `/var/lib/krb5kdc/…`) or the global `/etc/krb5.conf`. (It doesn't really matter which.) Both `krb5.conf` and `kdc.conf` have manual pages.

```
[logging]
    kdc = SYSLOG
    # kdc = STDERR
```

My first guess is that you haven't *created* a realm yet, using `kdb5_util create`.

Comment: There's nothing in `/var/lib/krb5kdc` (the directory exists, but is empty), and neither `kdc.conf` or `krb5.conf` have a logging section, though I suppose I could add one…

Comment: A `man` page for `krb5.conf` would be useful, but `man krb5.conf` gets me `No manual entry for krb5.conf` (Ubuntu precise). The man page for `kdc.conf` exists, and *even references* a supposed `krb5.conf` man page in section 5, but `man` can't find it.